# Can't both add extra newlines in find -printf and pipe output through sort

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to print out the top 10 largest files in my current directory.

For now I'm using

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s %p\n'|sort -nr| head
```

I'm not sure how to add an additional newline after each file size. Typing `\n\n` doesn't do anything, or `\n\\n`. I also need a tab before each line as well.

Comment: CNR. `-printf '%s %p\n\n'` works perfectly here (findutils 4.6.0).

Comment: that said, `sort -nr` will be removing your newlines, or at least, throwing them out of order.

Comment: Why are you using newlines for this job at all? A NUL-delimited stream is the right tool for the task.

Comment: Not portable or robust, but you can probably just do `ls -S | sed 10q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use newlines here. They're the wrong tool for the job: Filenames can contain literal newlines, so you don't know if a newline in `find`'s output here came from your format string or a literal filename. Moreover, by default, `sort` uses newlines as record separators, so the empty lines and the names they were previously next to are no longer next to each other when it's done (since they've been... well... *sorted* into different locations).

So -- generate your output in a format that makes sense given the content restraints, and then reformat it into what you actually **want** for output later:

```
while IFS= read -r -d$'\t' size && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf '\t%s\n\n' "$filename"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%s\t%p\0'|sort -znr|head -z)
```

Note that this is full of GNUisms (`sort -z`, `head -z`) -- but `find -printf` is a GNUism itself.

---

By way of understanding this code, some pointers:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001): "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"
- [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003): "How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?"
- [Process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst): The `<( ... )` syntax used to expose the output from the pipeline as a file.
- [The `printf` builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf): A discussion of the bash `printf` command.

Comment: Would there be a more noob friendly way to take the output that I've printed to a file and then print that to standard output but with a new line and a tab in between each line?

Comment: ...yes, but if you're making code less efficient (in this case, adding a requirement that it use temporary files) in order to get a more familiar syntax, I'm inclined to call that a bad trade. Better to make the formerly-unfamiliar syntax familiar.

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- you'd change the middle line to `printf '\t%s\n\n' "$filename"` to get the exact format you're asking for with the answer given above.